# XERO API: Synchronising Attachment changes for Xero Invoices

Tags: ruby, xero-api

My Xero app synchronises itself on a regular basis and checks for any Invoice changes. If there is an changes to an invoice it will be generally picked up when the `ifModifiedSince` option is supplied.

This is the query command:

```
client.Invoice.all(
            page: source_page, 
            modified_since: @invoices_modified_since, 
            where: { date_is_greater_than_or_equal_to: @from, date_is_less_than_or_equal_to: @to }
            )
```

The problem is that I want to receive an update if an attachment has been added to the invoice. At the moment this doesn't trigger an Invoice update.

Is there anyway of knowing when an attachment on an invoice has been added or removed?

Here is my testing case:

1. Make a new Invoice (no attachment)
2. Add an attachment to the invoice
3. Resync and watch the Xero log
4. Remove the attachment from the invoice
5. Resync and watch Xero log

Expected: should see invoice being sent by Xero for syncing/updating

Actual: No invoice data is sent by the Xero API

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been requested on Xero UsetrVoice page [here](https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/90148-update-the-updateddateutc-when-an-invoice-is-modif). The intended purpose of 
UpdatedDateUTC primarily is to see payments added to invoice. Unfortunately Addition/Changed to attachments to an invoice doesn't change the updateddateutc.   If you’re keen to see this implemented soon please vote for the feature request, that way you can also get automatically intimated once this has been implemented.

Hope this helps.

Cheers
Sri

Comment: Cheers! Haha. Was just in the process of writing it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Xero and they got back to me. That is pretty good to begin with!!

Anyway, at this point there is no way to do what I want. According to Xero the main use of the update/modified_since feature is to see payment changes.

However, it has been submitted as a feature request to Xero and there is more information here too: https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/90148-update-the-updateddateutc-when-an-invoice-is-modif

Perhaps there is a different way, but not via the modified since option.